# DC.js | How can i get .title (tooltip) to work on boxplot?

Tags: javascript, dc.js

I have a number of boxplots on a time x axis. I've switched off brushing, because I want the tooltip (.title) to work instead. However it's not working. Grateful for any suggestions! Here's my code:

```
distTime.width(350)
        .height(150)
        .margins({left:50,right:10,top:0,bottom:30})
        .dimension(timeDim)
        .group(premiumGroup)
        .clipPadding(30)
        .brushOn(false)
        .renderTitle(true)
        .title(function(d){ return "emma"; })
        .boxWidth(20)
        .colors("steelblue")
        .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)
        .x(d3.time.scale())
        .round(d3.time.years.round)
        .xUnits(d3.time.years)
        .elasticY(true);

    distTime.yAxis().tickFormat(d3.format('s'));
    distTime.yAxis().ticks(5);

function calc_domain(chart) {
    var min = d3.min(chart.group().all(), function(kv) { return kv.key; }),
        max = d3.max(chart.group().all(), function(kv) { return kv.key; });
    //max = d3.time.year.offset(max, 1);
    chart.x().domain([min, max]);
}
distTime.on('preRender', calc_domain);
distTime.on('preRedraw', calc_domain);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the titles with a pretransition event handler:

```
  chart.on('pretransition', function(chart) {
    chart.selectAll('rect.box')
      .append('title')
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.key + ' (mean ' + d3.mean(d.value) + ')';
      });
  });
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rwbmrzu9/8/

[image: box with tooltip]

This adds the title to the main rectangle (`'rect.box'`) of each box-and-whiskers; inspect the DOM to see other pieces to customize, or use `'g.box'` to add the title to the whole thing.

Note that the data will include an array of all the individual values for the box in `d.value`; here I'm showing the mean.